# fmt.Sscanf doesn't properly read hexadecimal

Tags: string, go, hex, scanf

I'm having trouble reading back a value that I've serialized to hex format. The following code produces a value of 0x14 when I format an integer. However, when I try to read that value back from the string, I get invalid results. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

I have pre-existing text files that I'm parsing with multiple lines that include this format, so serializing into a different format will not be a viable solution. I need work with this specific format.

According to the go docs, this should work: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

> The verbs behave analogously to those of Printf. For example, %x will scan an integer as a hexadecimal number, and %v will scan the default representation format for the value. The Printf verbs %p and %T and the flags # and + are not implemented. For floating-point and complex values, all valid formatting verbs (%b %e %E %f %F %g %G %x %X and %v) are equivalent and accept both decimal and hexadecimal notation (for example: "2.3e+7", "0x4.5p-8") and digit-separating underscores (for example: "3.14159_26535_89793").

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    encode := 20
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%#x", encode)) // 0x14

    var decode int
    numRead, err := fmt.Sscanf("0x14", "%#x", &decode)
    fmt.Println(decode, numRead, err) // 0 1 bad verb '%#' for integer

    numRead, err = fmt.Sscanf("0x14", "%x", &decode)
    fmt.Println(decode, numRead, err) // 0 1 nil
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%x` verb will scan a hexadecimal integer but not the `0x` prefix. You may add that prefix to the format string:

```
var decode int
numRead, err := fmt.Sscanf("0x14", "0x%x", &decode)
fmt.Println(decode, numRead, err)
```

This will properly scan the `0x14` input into the decimal integer value of `20` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wrvHQAwR2Mk)):

```
20 1 <nil>
```

Another option is to use the `%v` verb which handles the prefix and detects that it is a hexadecimal number:

```
var decode int
numRead, err := fmt.Sscanf("0x14", "%v", &decode)
fmt.Println(decode, numRead, err) // Outputs: 20 <nil>
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q88-n742QKj). This has the flexibility that the input may be specified in a number of bases, the base will be detected from the prefix ("*%v will scan the default representation format for the value"*), such as `0x` for hexa, `0` for octal, `0b` for binary.

You may also use [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) where you can specify a `base == 0`, in which case *"the base is implied by the string's prefix: base 2 for "0b", base 8 for "0" or "0o", base 16 for "0x", and base 10 otherwise"*.

```
decode, err := strconv.ParseInt("0x14", 0, 64)
fmt.Println(decode, err)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MBamhPv_K-x).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the extra effort you put in to provide alternatives and I learned some new tricks :)

Answer (score 5):

Note this sentence in the docs:

> The Printf verbs %p and %T and the flags # and + are not implemented.

So:

```
var decode int
numRead, err := fmt.Sscanf("0x14", "0x%x", &decode)
fmt.Println(decode, numRead, err) 

numRead, err = fmt.Sscanf("14", "%x", &decode)
fmt.Println(decode, numRead, err)
```

Comment: Ah, I did read that but for some reason it didn't register that I needed to add the 0x prefix myself in the format string since I couldn't use equivalent formats. Thanks for the dummy check!